# PyCharm won't create configuration to run

Tags: python, pycharm

For the last 2 days PyCharm won't create the configuration setting to run my Python files and I have to create them manually to run my codes.

Before that PyCharm created those configuration setting for me, and all I had to do was just press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linux or Mac, I've seen a similar (not the same) issue where the app (in this case PyCharm) was installed with `root` user via `sudo` and then the executed as normal user, that then won't have permissions to create/change the configuration files, which in PyCharm's case is the `.idea` folder in your project folder.

If this was previously working, maybe an update to PyCharm while you were running as `root` may cause the same issue (folder `root` becomes the owner of the folder and normal user can't change it).

Comment: nope, I'm using windows 10 and "PyCharm 2018.2.3 (Professional Edition) Build #PY-182.4323.5, built on August 22, 2018"

Comment: Maybe you already have a configuration with the same name. In the configurations drop down, click Edit Configurations and then delete any existing configurations. When you create the new one, it should persist.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+F10?